# Android studio suddenly getting Resource linking failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle

resource linking failed i got this error suddenly while working with my android studio sdk version 28 i am getting below error in my build what to do can some will help me with my problem

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processDebugResources'.     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>     at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   linking failed Output: 
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_default.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found. error: failed linking file resources.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\3630ad447130c7775c2d71e53cbfe7c2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0 Output: 
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_default.xml:19:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21:
>   AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka
>   com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found.
>        error: failed linking file resources. Command: C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\3630ad447130c7775c2d71e53cbfe7c2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:527)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>     ... 33 more Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   linking failed Output: 
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_default.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found.
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\0b800212ff172d351e952bcb74f957f1\res\color\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21:
>   error: attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha)
>   not found. error: failed linking file resources.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Users\vijay.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\3630ad447130c7775c2d71e53cbfe7c2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           C:\Users\vijay\AndroidStudioProjects\New folder\MyplaceMySaloon\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:525)
>     ... 49 more

Comment: "attribute alpha (aka com.example.vijay.myplacemysaloon:alpha) not found"

Comment: @Tarun have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I have just had a very similiar problem.

It seems as if the resource file R has been deleted off. In my case it disappeared when I created a Google Maps activity.

Try:
**Build -> Clean Project**
That cleans the gradle file

Alternatively:
**File->Invalidate Caches**
Then sync the project with gradle files

Give these a go and see if it does the trick.
I found that creating a new project and copying and pasting the code from the 'old' project worked best though. It does take a little time because you'd have to create all xml files and java classes again, but considering how many hours I have browsed the web to find a fix, creating a new project only took about 30 min- of course that depends on the size of your project. Just make sure (if you do go ahead and copy and paste the code) that you dont accidentally copy the package names from the 'old' project into your new one if your new project is named differently.

Good luck!